# How to negate MATCH or SEARCH in google sheets conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

This works:

```
=MATCH($F1, "searchterm")
```

and this works:

```
=SEARCH($F1, "searchterm")
```

These don't:

```
=NOT(MATCH($F1, "searchterm"))
```

```
=NOT(SEARCH($F1, "searchterm"))
```

Because [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) and [`SEARCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) return positional values, not booleans.

What is the suggested method to negate the search, to highlight rows not matching the search condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use iserr

```
=ISERR(search($F1, "searchterm"))
```

or

```
=ISNA(match($F1, "searchterm"))
```

Comment: I believe for the MATCH one it should either be ISERROR() or ISNA(). ISERR() won't return TRUE for #N/A errors.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, thank you. Can confirm it works for SEARCH, but not for MATCH.

Comment: @lys in MATCH case you need to add 3rd parameter (empty, 0 or FALSE) - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70718180/5632629

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH($F1, "searchterm", ), FALSE)
```

if this is about conditional formatting try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH($F1, "searchterm", ))=""
```

or:

```
=(IFERROR(MATCH($F1, "searchterm", ))="")*($F1<>"")
```

[image]